# John 1:1 Jesus true God or false god?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Isaiah 9:6, we read that Jesus is called the “mighty God” Yet, Jehovah God is called “mighty God” at Isaiah 10:20-21. Are there two “mighty Gods”? The real issue is not whether other beings are called “gods,” but which category of “god” does Jesus fall under? Does He fall under the category of being the true God or a false god? While Jehovah’s Witnesses assert that there is a category of “gods” that is neither true nor false and that these “gods” hold the title of “god” due to their power and authority, Scripture reveals that this is not the case. For example, at Psalm 82:6-7, Israelite judges were called “gods” in sarcasm because these judges (who thought of themselves a “gods”) were reviling the true God by their unrighteous judgments. Psalm 82 is a psalm of condemnation for these judges who acted as if they were “gods” in that they made life and death decisions for others, but they would ultimately “die like men” —thus proving the infinite difference between the true God and the mightiest of mortals.

At 2 Corinthians 4:4, Satan is addressed as “the god of this world.” Since it is obvious that Satan is a false god, he is addressed as “god” because pagans and unbelievers throughout history have worshipped him by serving false idol “gods” made of wood and stone, powered by demons (1 Corinthians 10:20). Yet, despite Satan’s authority as “god of this world,” the demons recognize that Satan is not a real “god.” At James 2:19, the Bible declares that even the demons recognize that there is only “one God.” Since there is only one true God (John 17:3) who has revealed Himself as the “only God” (1 Timothy 1:17), Jesus is either in the true God category of being Jehovah God Himself, or He is a counterfeit god who is a false god. There is no middle ground. While Scripture reveals that there is only one God “by nature” and that all other “so-called gods” are false gods (1 Corinthians 8:5-6), Jesus is “by nature” the one and only true God. https://www.4jehovah.org/jesus-is-god-chapter-7-yes-you-should-believe-in-the-trinity/

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question, or if it is one then it is one that different Christians will disagree with. To avoid this being closed as a discussion questions, please state which Christian group you want an answer from.

Comment: John 5:26,27 seems to say that God the Father made his son into a God too.

Answer (score 2):

You can see several places in the New Testament saying Jesus is God. He is the true God, but he is not the same as God the Father. There is only one true God but there are three different persons in God, and Jesus is one of the three. This is a mystery but it is what Bible says.

John 1:1

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
> John 1:14
> And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us,

Jesus is the Word, and the Word is God. Jesus became flesh(incarnation).

1 John 5:20

> And we know that the Son of God has come and has given us understanding, so that we may know him who is true; and we are in him who is true, in his Son Jesus Christ. He is the true God and eternal life.

Jesus is a true God.

If you believe what the Bible testifies is always true, then you should know that Jesus is the true God. And God the Father is the true God as well. The Holy Spirit is the Power of God and he is also God.

You cannot say that Jesus is a false God because Jesus identified himself as lower than God the Father. Jesus is on the lower rank but He has the same power and knowledge as the Father God. He was the one who created the Universe. The Holy Spirit was sent after Jesus ascended to Heaven, for the work of Salvation.

And if you read Proverbs 8:22-31 you will see that Jesus was with God when God was creating the Universe. He was with him. And if he was just a mere creature or false God, he would not be mentioned at all.

Colossians 1:16

> For by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him.

Heaven and earth were created through Jesus and for Jesus.

Comment: Re 1 John 5:20, "He is the true God and eternal life." Ya, but who is 'he' here? Scholars debate this - it could refer to either Jesus or the Father. "we are in **him** who is true, in **his Son** Jesus Christ" The Son, or Him of whom Jesus is the Son?

Comment: John hasn't called Jesus God anywhere, why would he start here? The subject is clearly about God and what HE did through His son from v18. He is the true God, as noted in John 17:3 - clearly Jesus is not God here, so he cannot be in 5:20 either.

Answer (score 1):

> we have known that of God we are, and the whole world in the evil doth lie; and we have known that the Son of God is come, and hath given us a
> mind, that we may know Him who is true, and we are in Him who is true,
> in His Son Jesus Christ; this one is the true God and the life
> age-during! - 1 John 5:19-20 (YLT)

We have known that we are of God and that the Son of God has given us a mind to know Him who is true.  Who is this "Him"?  Contextually it is either God or the Son of God.

If "Him who is true" is God then the verse says, "that we may know Him who is true (God) and we are in Him who is true (God), in His Son Jesus Christ."

If "Him who is true" is the Son of God then the verse says, "that we may know Him who is true (the Son of God) and we are in Him who is true (the Son of God), in His Son Jesus Christ."

The second option doesn't work because Jesus Christ is given as the Son of "Him who is true":

> and we are in Him who is true, in His Son Jesus Christ

So, "Him who is true" is God.

Colossians 3 uses similar language:

> for ye did die, and your life hath been hid with the Christ in God

Scripture often portrays believers as "in Christ" and Jesus prayed that those who believe in Him may have the unity that he and the Father have:

> that they all may be one, as Thou Father art in me, and I in Thee; that they also in us may be one, that the world may believe that Thou didst send me. - John 17:21

So believers are in Christ in God.  We are in Him who is true (God), in His Son Jesus Christ.

We are in Christ and Christ is in God.  This is the true God.  The whole thing that has just been described.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqguw.png

Answer (score -1):

> The phrase in Isaiah 9:6 that most English versions translate as “Mighty God” is 'el gibbor' in the Hebrew. That very phrase, in the plural form, is used Ezekiel 32:21 of “heroes” and mighty men.

> Actually, “mighty god” would not be a bad translation if people realized that in the Hebrew language the word “god/God” (Elohim; also El) had a much wider range of application than it does in English. People familiar with the Semitic languages know that a man who is acting with God’s authority can be called “god.” Although English makes a clear distinction between “God” and “god,” the Hebrew language, which has only capital letters, cannot.

Excerpt from REV Commentary.

There is no doubt that Satan IS the god of this world. Is he the true God - the creator and sustainer of life? No. But he IS a god. Similarly, Jesus has also qualified to be a 'god' of the *new age* in which he rules under his Father and God Yahweh.

This is what the prophecy in Isaiah looks forward to:

For a child will be born to us, a son will be given to us,
and the government will be on his shoulders. And he will call his name
Wonderful Counsellor, Mighty Hero, ***father of the coming age***, Prince of Peace.

Jesus IS the son promised when the logos become flesh, and he was born of Mary, as mentioned in John.

Jesus is the true son of the true God.

> And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent. John 17:3

There is only one TRUE God and there is only one son of that God who is the one Isaiah spoke of and the one God would send to be the Saviour of the world.

John hasn't called Jesus God anywhere; why would he start here in John 5:20? The subject is clearly about God and what HE did through His son from v18. There is one true God, as noted in John 17:3 - clearly Jesus is not that God here ( because it was God who sent him), so he cannot be in 5:20 either.

If we insist on interpreting a verse in isolation as we personally choose instead of allowing scripture to be *self-interpreting*, then we make John a liar in 17:3 not just John, but Jesus too!

> Jesus spoke these things; and raising His eyes to heaven... 17:1

Comment: Cults don't believe Jesus is God in the flesh is going to hell!! Case closed!